# Почему не работает явный height в пикселях для блочного элемента?

Tags: css, height

Ситуация максимально простая: есть блок, внутри него контейнер, внутри контейнера еще один див. Явная высота в пикселях задана только самому младшему диву.В результате высота у всех блоков равна высоте текста внутри. Может быть глупый вопрос, но я в упор не понимаю в чем дело.

```css
.titleWletter {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<section class="main__blog blog">
  <div class="blog__container">
    <div class="blog__titleWletter titleWletter">
      <h3 class="titleWletter__title">
        Let's blog
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Не понимаю, всё же работает

Comment: Всё отлично работает, высота всех div'ов и вообще всей страницы ровно 180 пикселей https://i.stack.imgur.com/TO1i6.png

Comment: У меня в отдельном файле этот же самый код тоже сработал как нужно, но в основном проекте все та же ерунда. Никаких ошибок за пределами этого фрагмента в основном проекте нет. Не может ли это быть из-за проблем с браузером или самим редактором кода или еще по какой-то технической причине?

Answer (score 0):

Всё работает:

```css
.titleWletter {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 180px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<section class="main__blog blog">
  <div class="blog__container">
    <div class="blog__titleWletter titleWletter">
      <h3 class="titleWletter__title">
        Let's blog
      </h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```